# Correct way to cache data in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to asynchronously load data into vuex that is static but is used by multiple routes.I only want to fetch the data once and only when a route that needs it is visited. This is what I'm currently doing but I'm not sure if this is the correct convention or if there is a better/more Vueish way.

```
// store.js

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    _myData: null,
  },
  getters: {
    myData: (state) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      if(state._myData){
        resolve(state._myData);
      } else {
        axios.get('http://myData.com/')
        .then(myData => {
          state._myData = myData;
          resolve(state._myData);
        });
      }
    })
  }
});

// ProfilePage.vue

<template>
 <div>{{myData}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myData:null
    }
  },
  async created(){
   this.myData = await this.$store.getters.myData;
  }
}
</script>

// AboutPage.vue

<template>
 <div>{{myData}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myData:null
    }
  },
  async created(){
   this.myData = await this.$store.getters.myData;
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a correct way to do what you want but it is not the way you are doing it. Vue is quite strict on "Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

This means you should only alter the store state through a mutation, then use your getter only to get the data. You should also use an action to commit the mutation. So for what you are trying to do you should try it like this.

```
// AnyPage.vue

<template>
 <div>{{myData}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myData:null
    }
  },
  async created(){
    if(this.$store.state._myData === null) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('getData')
    }
    this.myData = this.$store.getters.myData;
  }
}
</script>
```

then in your store:

```
// store.js

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    _myData: null,
  },
  getters: {
    myData: (state) => state._myData,
  }
  mutations: {
    SET_DATA(state, data) {
      state._myData = data
    }
  }
  actions: {
    getData({ context }){
        axios.get('http://myData.com/')
        .then(res => {
          context.commit('SET_DATA', res)
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You should read up in the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) which covers it all pretty well.

Comment: Is there any reason for having a getter in your example? Couldn't I just access the state variable directly?

Comment: @als9xd the example above doesn't essentially need one but using getters is vue best practice and is essential if you need to compute the store state, for instance running a filter function. It's a good habit to have.

Comment: getters are ideal when multiple components need the same data https://codeburst.io/vuex-getters-are-great-but-dont-overuse-them-9c946689b414

Comment: This works when used with `<div>{{myData}}</div>`, but that is not very practical. It breaks in any real world use case, for example `<div>{{myData.aProp}}</div>`. At render, `aProp` is null and will result in console errors. What would be the best way to avoid that?

Comment: Without knowing what your `myData` object contains I cannot say what this issue could be, but there is no reason you can't extract a property from it. If you are having a problem you could try making `myData` a computed property as the other answer shows although i would access it using mapGetters.

Answer (score 5):

> Action handlers receive a context object which exposes the same set of methods/properties on the store instance, so you can call context.commit to commit a mutation, or **access the state** and getters via **context.state** and context.getters. 
>   https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

try this:

```
// AnyPage.vue

<template>
 <div>{{myData}}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    myData () {
      return this.$store.state.myData
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('getData')
  }
}
</script>
```

in store file:

```
// store.js

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    myData: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_DATA(state, data) {
      state.myData = data
    }
  }
  actions: {
    getData({ context }){
        if (context.state.myData === null) {
            axios.get('http://myData.com/')
            .then(res => {
                context.commit('SET_DATA', res)
            })
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: How is this answer useful? Seems it was written after the other Andrew's answer and you're essentially saying exactly the same? :-/

Comment: hi, here i used computed property, wish make the variable reactive